# What does it mean for a complex differential form on a complex manifold to be real?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

I am trying to read Kobayashi's "Differential geometry of complex vector bundles". There are many places where a complex differential form is referred to as being **real**. e.g

Chapter I, Proposition 7.24 p. 28 " A closed **real** $(p,p)$ form $\omega$ on a compact Kähler manifold M is cohomologous to zero if and only if $ \omega = id' d'' \phi $ for some **real** $(p-1,p-1)$-form $\phi. $ "

Similarly, p. 41 Chapter II, Proposition 2.23 " Given any closed **real** $(1,1)$-form $\phi$ representing $c_{1}(E),$ there is an Hermitian structure $h$ in $E$ such that $\phi = c_{1}(E)$ provided $M$ is compact Kähler."

What does it mean? Does it mean that the coefficients are **real valued** function? Or does it mean that it is the **same under complex conjugation**?
i.e.  $\bar{\phi} = \phi ? $

To be more explicit,

Let $\alpha, \beta : \mathbb{C}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be real valued smooth functions and let $$ \phi = [\alpha(z_{1}, z_{2}) + i \beta(z_{1}, z_{2})] dz_{1}\wedge d\bar{z_{2}} -  [\alpha(z_{1}, z_{2}) - i \beta(z_{1}, z_{2})] dz_{2}\wedge d\bar{z_{1}} . $$

This is a $(1,1)$-form on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ with the property that $\bar{\phi} = \phi, $ since $ \overline{dz_{1}\wedge d\bar{z_{2}}} = - dz_{2}\wedge d\bar{z_{1}},$ but this is a **real valued** form only if $\beta \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2}.$ Or does $\phi$ being **real** mean something else?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means if you write $dz_j=dx_j+\sqrt{-1}dy_j$ and expand everything you are left with only real coefficients. For example, a $(1,1)$-form $\xi dz\wedge d \overline{z}$ is real if writing $\xi=\alpha+\sqrt{-1}\beta$ and $dz=dx+\sqrt{-1}dy$,$$\xi dz\wedge d\overline{z}=(\alpha+\sqrt{-1}\beta)(-2\sqrt{-1}dx\wedge dy)$$ has real coefficient, i.e., $(\alpha+\sqrt{-1}\beta)(-2\sqrt{-1})$ is a real function.

Comment: I am not absolutely sure, but I think what is you said is always equivalent to requiring $\bar{\phi} = \phi .$ 

At any rate, your answer clarifies the point that being **real** and being **real-valued** are distinct notions. My example above is real, since in real co-ordinates, it would be $2 \alpha ( dx_{1}\wedge dx_{2} + dy_{1}\wedge dy_{2}) + 2 \beta ( dx_{1}\wedge dy_{2} + dx_{2}\wedge dy_{1}).$ But it is not real-valued unless $\beta = 0.$ Thanks.

Comment: You’re welcome, yes they are equivalent

Comment: So when we say that a Kahler manifold is a complex manifold with a symplectic form and other compatibility conditions, don't we mean the symplectic form is **real valued** as opposed to what you said? Or do we mean the Kahler form satisfies $w = \bar {w}$?